# Polynomially larger - confusion

Tags: polynomial-math

I am studying for my algorithms class. I have a question in context to the Masters theorem:

How is n.log2(n) polynomially larger than n^(log4(3))

(log2(x) = log to the base 2 of x 
 log4(x) = log to the base 4 of x)
(Note: This is a solved problem on page.95 of 'Introduction to Algorithms' by Cormen et.al.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log4(3) is less than 1, and so n^(log4(3)) is less than n^1 = n, which is less than n*log2(n).

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation!